# is there a way to get a if statement that says if a number is between 1 and 5, print something

Tags: python, if-statement, range

if money == (1, 799999):
print("You're a natural!)

I need to make it so, if the money variable is = to anything in between 1 and 799999 it can return a print. But i cant find anything to do it

Comment: `if 1 <= money <= 799999: print('You're a natural')` Do you need only integers?

Comment: Yes! thank you, but how did it not pop up on the list of "maybe this will answer your question." when i posted this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```py
if money>=1 and money<=799999:
    print("You are natural.")
```

Hope it works.....